# Attaching cookie to WorkLight Adapter response header

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I am developing a mobile app using WorkLight 5.0.6 and I would like to attach a secure cookie to the response returned by an adapter.

We are not using a WorkLight Authentication realm because we do not wish to "bind" the session to a specific WL server in a clustered production environment. We authenticate the session by calling a sign-on adapter which authenticates the user details against a back end system. As part of the response from the sign-on adapter call I would like to create a secure cookie (http only) containing the authenticated information and attach it to the response returned from the sign-on adapter. The cookie should also be included in the header for subsequent Adapter made from the application call to the server.

Regards,

```
 Tom.
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest trying to create a custom Worklight authenticator that communicates with your backend. Documentation for a custom authenticator can be found here:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/08_04_Custom_Authenticator_and_Login_Module.pdf

To answer your question, here is how I would approach it without using a custom authenticator:

- Make the adapter call to authenticate from the client

> function authenticate(username, password){
>
> ```
>   var invocationData = {
>           adapter : 'authenticationAdapter',
>           procedure : 'authenticate',
>           parameters : [username, password]
>   };
>
>   WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
>       onSuccess : authSuccess,
>       onFailure : authFailure
>   });
> ```
>
> }

- Get the cookie from the response on the client side and save it (I suggest saving using JSONStore which can also encrypt the saved cookie)

> ```
> function authSuccess(response){
>     console.log("Auth Success");
>     var myCookie = response.invocationResult.responseHeaders.CookieName
>
>     // Save cookie somehow
> }
> ```

- On subsequent adapter calls, send the cookie from the client along with each request

> function adapterRequestForProtectedResource(){
>
> var mySecureCookie = getMyCookieFromLocalStorage();
>
> ```
>   var invocationData = {
>           adapter : 'protectedResourceAdapter',
>           procedure : 'getResource',
>           parameters : [mySecureCookie]
>   };
>
>   WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
>       onSuccess : success,
>       onFailure : failure
>   });
> ```
>
> }

- On the adapter, set the cookie in the header

  function getResource(secureCookie) {

  ```
  // Secure cookie must be of the form:  "CookieName=cookievalue"

  var input = {
      method : 'get',
      returnedContentType : 'json',
      path : "/resource",
      headers: {"Cookie": secureCookie}
  };

  return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
  ```

  }